# Chrome API / command line for external software

Tags: windows, google-chrome, winapi, google-chrome-devtools

Is there any programming interface or command line for Chrome to get information about current state of the browser? Like currently navigated URL or list of plugins/extension installed?

I'm building a windows-based service that needs to check what is currently browsed web page in Chrome. Is there any way to check this without building an additional browser extension/plugin?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not what your looking for (yet), but the @ChromiumDev twitter account recently mentioned a CLI for Mac 
https://github.com/prasmussen/chrome-cli

I don't know how much info you get out of it though.